# Does await a synchonous method with Task.FromResult make sense

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

What benefit is there to await a synchronous repo.GetCategories call for the availability of the endpoint?

My first mind was that makes no sense. But I am not sure.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string country)
{
    var result = repo.GetCategories(new List<string> { country});
    return await Task.FromResult(Ok(result));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My first mind was that makes no sense.

Your mind is right. If the ongoing operating isn't asynchronous, why wrap it in a `Task` at all? Unless you're overriding a method declared in a base class which you have no control over, this would be better:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string country)
{
    var result = repo.GetCategories(new List<string> { country});
    return Ok(result);
}
```

If you have no control over the said method, then there is no point in awaiting it. `Task.FromResult` will merely wrap your synchronous result with a `TaskCompletionSource<T>`. There is nothing inherently asynchronous happening behind the scenes.

Comment: @Luaan No, there is no such necessity.

Answer (score 0):

From availability standpoint, it doesn't help one bit - you're still blocking the thread by the `GetCategories` call. You'd get equivalent behaviour from using

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string country)
{
    var result = repo.GetCategories(new List<string> { country });
    return Ok(result);
}
```

or

```
[HttpGet]
public Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string country)
{
    var result = repo.GetCategories(new List<string> { country });
    return Task.FromResult(Ok(result));
}
```

They work identically except for treating exceptions differently (in the `async`+`await` case, they are always wrapped in a `Task`), but that doesn't matter if you're awaiting the `Get` anyway. It would make a difference if you were using manual continuations or delayed awaits, though.

In the end, if you have plenty of calls like this, the web server / application will simply create more threads to handle the requests, so you don't even hurt availability exactly - the overhead is bigger, though; you can handle more concurrent requests with asynchronous code, and it usually takes less memory to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense the purpose for the Await keyword is to be used with the Async keyword to produce code that runs asynchronously in rich winForm eviroments to make a UI more responsive with handling long running methods, it might make sense if your Repo. GetCategories takes a few seconds to complete, but not in this context of a Web request.

Comment: That's just one tiny part of the usefullness of `await`. And in any case, it wouldn't make the UI responsive anyway, because there's nothing asynchronous about the "async" method here - it will complete entirely synchronously, blocking the calling thread.

Comment: that was the point i was trying to make, i didn't know about the blocking part, but thanks for the info, i will try and clean up my responce to be more clear